# How to properly declare/use a character with a particular ASCII code in out.write?

Tags: c++

I have the following buffer

```
std::vector<char> vecBuffer;
```

the following delimiter

```
char delim = char(167);
```

The following replace function

```
std::replace(vecBuffer.begin(), vecBuffer.end(), delim, ' ');
```

And the following output routines

```
out.write(&vecBuffer[0], x.length());
out.write(delim, 1);
```

However the last line gives me the error

```
error: invalid conversion from 'char' to 'const char*' [-fpermissive]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`delim` is a `char` and `write` seems to expect a pointer. So get its address:

```
out.write(&delim, 1);
```

Answer (score 0):

correct syntax would be,

```
out.write((const char*)&delim, 1);
```

Comment: No need for the cast, it just confuses the reader -- implicit conversions from pointer to const pointer are just fine